# Cannot get realtime calculate result use javascript in foreach condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

now im working laravel project for implementing real time calculate result using javascript. but the condition is, the real time calculate is inside in foreach() code. here is the case

[image]

- Background Yellow is `<input>` code
- Background Red is realtime calculate result by Javascript

Realtime calculate have 2 way to implement :

1. Get result "Total Each" for each row
2. Get result "Grand Total" for each column

from now. i just able to get "Grand Total" for column "Price in dollar" and Column "discount".

the problem is :

1. I still not able to get realtime result for each row "Total Each" , `E2 = C2-(C2*D2), E3= C3-(C3*D3), E4= C4-(C4*D4), E5= C5-(C5*D5)`
2. Grand total for column "Total Each", E6 = E2 + E3 + E4 + E5

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".price").keyup(function() {
    var totalprice = 0;
    $.each($(".price"), function(key, input) {
      if (input.value && !isNaN(input.value)) {
        totalprice += parseFloat(input.value);
      }
    });
    $("#totalprice").html(totalprice);
  });


  $(".discount").keyup(function() {
    var totaldiscount = 0;
    $.each($(".discount"), function(key, input) {
      if (input.value && !isNaN(input.value)) {
        totaldiscount += parseFloat(input.value);
      }
    });
    $("#totaldiscount").html(totaldiscount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Items</td>
    <td>Price in dollar</td>
    <td>Discount %</td>
    <td>Total Each</td>
  </tr>

  @foreach ($buyers as $key => $val)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $val['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $val['items'] }}</td>
    <td><input class='price' name="price[ {{$key}} ][ {{$val['id']}} ]" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class='discount' name="discount[ {{$key}} ][ {{$val['id']}} ]" type="text"></td>
    <td> ?get total each? </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Grand Total</td>
    <td><span id="totalprice"></span></td>
    <td><span id="totaldiscount"></span></td>
    <td> get "grand total" from "total each" </td>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the PHP with RENDERED HTML -  it is not a PHP issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the same function on any change

1. Added thead, tbody and tfoot and fixed the rowspan for the total
2. Used jQuery map and JS reduce to get the totals
3. Navigated the fields using closest. You can simplify the `$(input).closest("td").next().find("input").val();` if you give the line total a class

```js
$(function() {

  $("tbody").on("input", function() {
    const totalPrice = $(".price").map(function(i, input) {
      const val = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
      $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val)
      return val;
    }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)
    $("#totalprice").text(totalPrice);

    const totalEach = $(".price").map(function(i, input) {
      const price = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
      let  discount = $(input).closest("td").next().find("input").val();
      discount = discount && !isNaN(discount) ? +discount : 0;
      const val = (price - price * (discount/100))
      $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val.toFixed(2))
      return val;
    }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)

    $("#totalEach").text(totalEach.toFixed(2))

    const totalDiscount = $(".discount").map(function(i, input) {
      return input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
    }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc += cur;
      return acc
    }, 0)
    $("#totaldiscount").text(totalDiscount);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Price in dollar</th>
      <th>Discount %</th>
      <th>Total Each</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td><input class='price' name="price[xxx]" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class='discount' name="discount[xxx]" type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td><input class='price' name="price[yyy]" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class='discount' name="discount[yyy]" type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Grand Total</td>
      <td><span id="totalprice"></span></td>
      <td><span id="totaldiscount"></span></td>
      <td id="totalEach"> </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for answeing but i still confuse for "total each" i just modifeid my question in problem section. please take a look.

Comment: I do not understand what you need. I total the amount in the extreme right at the bottom right

Comment: the discount total does not make sense by the way. You cannot accumulate discounts

Comment: thank you @mplungjan yes it work perfectly. abut the "total discount"  i still confuse for the formula. do you have idea?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. If you add 2% + 5% + 10% that is not 17%, we can CALCULATE the percent by taking totalEach*100/totalPrice

Comment: ah thank you. i will try to find the formula. but i have something to ask @mplungjan. for the JS code. how if the condition like this. on the table code. i use rowspan. so for the first row will set a different columns number for display the result. do i able to change it? i explain in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936170/cannot-display-correct-position-for-display-realtime-calculate-result-use-javasc?noredirect=1#comment111296270_62936170