# Cannot display correct position for display realtime calculate result use javascript

Tags: javascript, php

now im doing laravel project that have function calculate realtime result use javascript.

im following this link [Cannot get realtime calculate result use javascript in foreach condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910401/cannot-get-realtime-calculate-result-use-javascript-in-foreach-condition/62910780#62910780)

the calculate result is correct but not the position. i explain with image gif for more understand

[image]

if you see. at first. when i input 100. the second row display 100.00 that replace the `<input>` code on "discount(%)" columns. this is not correct.. 100.00 should display on "total" columns..

but different with the second and third rows. input price and discount. it will display result on "total" row. that condition is correct.

Datas is using `foreach()` code. the problem is only for first row on each name. the second row and the rest is correct display.

here is the code

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" width="10%">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" width="10%">Item</th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" width="10%">Price</th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" width="10%">Discount (%)</th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" width="10%">Total</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>  

    <tbody> 
        @foreach ($datas as $data) 
            @php
                $countitems = count($data->items);
            @endphp
            <tr> 
                <td rowspan="{{$countitems}}"> {{$record->name}} </td>  
                @foreach ($data->items as $key => $items)
                    @if ($key == 0) 
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%">{{ $items->name }} </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> <input class='price' type="number" name="price[$data->id][$key]" > </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> <input class='discount' type="number" name="discount[$data->id][$key]" > </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> </td> 
                    @endif 
                @endforeach 
            </tr>

            @for ($i = 1; $i < $countitems; $i++)
            <tr>
                @foreach ($data->items as $key => $items)
                    @if ($key == $i) 
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%">{{ $items->name }} </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> <input class='price' type="number" name="price[$data->id][$key]" > </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> <input class='discount' type="number" name="discount[$data->id][$key]" > </td>
                        <td class="text-center" width="10%"> </td> 
                    @endif 
                @endforeach  
            </tr> 
            @endfor

        @endforeach
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-right align-middle">Grand Total</th> 
            <th class="text-center align-middle"> <span id="totalprice"></span> </th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle"> <span id="totaldiscount"></span> </th>
            <th class="text-center align-middle" id="totalall"> </th>  
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
     
</table>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("tbody").on("input", function() {

        const totalprice = $(".price").map(function(i, input) {
            const val = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
            $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(3).text(val)
            return val;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)
        $("#totalprice").text(totalprice);


        const totalEach = $(".price").map(function(i, input) {
            const price = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
            let  discount = $(input).closest("td").next().find("input").val();
            discount = discount && !isNaN(discount) ? +discount : 0;
            const val = (price - price * (discount/100))
            $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(3).text(val.toFixed(2))
            return val;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)

        $("#totalall").text(totalEach.toFixed(2))

        const totaldiscount = $(".discount").map(function(i, input) {
            return input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc += cur;
            return acc;
        }, 0)
        $("#totaldiscount").text(totaldiscount);

    });

});
</script>
```

i guest the problem is in this code `$(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(3).text(val)`

but i still confuse how to solve this. please help

Comment: I don’t get what the problem is supposed to be, and the GIF isn’t really helping.

Comment: if you see. at first. when i input 100. the second row display 100.00 that replace the <input> code on "discount(%)" columns. this is not correct.. 100.00 should display on "total" columns.. but different with the second coloums. when i input price and discount. is will display on "total columns". that condition is correct.

Comment: do someone can help me?